# Custom Type. Assignment. How to copy instance and assign value part only?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, custom-type

I have this class:

```
public struct Field<T>
{
    public Field(int ordinal, int number)
        : this(ordinal, number, default(T))
    {

    }

    public Field(int ordinal, int number, T value)
        : this()
    {
        Ordinal = ordinal;
        Number = number;
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Ordinal
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static implicit operator Field<T>(T value)
    {
        Field<T> sarsField = new Field<T>();
        sarsField.Value = value;
        return sarsField;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Field<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
    // Declare field
    Field<DateTime> dateOfBirth = new Field<DateTime>(5, 25);

    // Set value
    dateOfBirth = DateTime.Today;
```

Problem is when i assign a `DateTime` to `dateOfBirth` it constructs a `new Field`, but looses the original values for `Ordinal` and `Number`. How do i change only the `Value` property when doing an implicit assignment? Is this possible?

If i made the setter public for `Value`, i could do this:

```
    // Set value
    dateOfBirth.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Achieves the desired result of setting only the `Value`, retaining `Ordinal` and `Number`. However, i would really like to do this implicitly. There are a number of places where i would like to replace the `Type` with `Field<Type>`. Hence, i am looking for an implicit solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Assignment overwrites the original variable; it doesn't allow you to just overwrite one property of the variable and leave the rest alone. Also, `struct`'s are supposed to be immutable, so modifying just the `Value` property, in any way, shouldn't be allowed. If you really want to allow this, I'd recommend using a `class` instead of a `struct`, and making the `Value` setter public.

However, if you want to keep it as a `struct`, I'd recommend something like this instead:

```
public Field<T> WithValue(T value)
{
    return new Field<T>(this.Ordinal, this.Number, value);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth.WithValue(DateTime.Today);
```

Also note, I'd strongly recommend making the `operator T` explicit, because it discards the `Ordinal` and `Numeric` values. See this note from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx):

> If a conversion operation can cause exceptions or lose information, you should mark it `explicit`.

Comment: +1, that's the reason why a [custom assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx) has to be `static`.